# Puma hangs after upgrade from Debian 9.7 to 9.8

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails

I have a frontend with Nginx talking to Puma over a Unix socket in two separate containers.  The base image for the Puma container is `ruby:2.5-slim`.  After clearing my Docker cache two days ago and attempting to deploy a newly built frontend, Puma stopped responding to requests.  I have traced the immediate cause back to a shift in the version of Debian used in the `ruby:2.5-slim` base image from Debian 9.7 to 9.8.  One thought is that there was a change in a relevant security setting between the two releases.

I've determined that rebuilding an image similar to `ruby:2.5-slim` but starting from Debian 9.7 resolves the immediate issue.  But I would like to deal with the deeper problem so that I don't have to pin the version of Debian.

When Puma is configured to run in single mode (0 workers), it serves up requests.  When Puma is configured to run in cluster mode (as it was before, with 1 or more workers), it hangs.

What are some next steps that will help to troubleshoot this issue?  Perhaps this is this just a bug I should file with Puma?

**Earlier troubleshooting details left for context:**

I have tried moving the socket from `/tmp/frontend.sock` to `/run/frontend.sock` to avoid potential private tmp visibility constraints.

I have since attempted to move the socket to a TCP socket and am seeing similar behavior.  In both cases, I'm also seeing the socket hang from within the Debian/Puma container:

```
# curl --unix /tmp/frontend.sock http://localhost/health # Unix domain socket
# curl localhost:3001/health # TCP socket
```

When the Nginx container is removed from the picture, a curl command to `localhost:3000/health` works as expected (but in this instance I'm running `bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000`, which ignores the Puma config).

"Hang" isn't the exact description.  When the pod first comes up, I'm sometimes able to get an initial page load from a browser after a *long* wait, perhaps suggesting there's a race that is subsequently locking up Puma threads. Later attempts just time out.  The CPU is mostly idle.

Kubernetes pod config here: https://gist.github.com/emwalker/0ffb1df6ef82d2566aebc45cd5660ce7

Comment: Is puma actually bound to port 3001?

Comment: There's two related experiments.  When Nginx is present, Puma has been bound to 3001, and Nginx is looking for it on that port.  When Nginx is taken away, I've been standing Puma up on 3000 (which is what the load balancer is configured for), using a rails command from within the container: `bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000`

Comment: An `lsof -i :3001` confirms that puma is bound to the port.

Comment: Hm. Why have a different config at all? That could be really confusing, especially since it's unnecessary. Just let Puma have its port all the time, and have nginx on a more conventional port (e.g. 8080) rather than one on which it's unexpected.

Comment: This was just temporary troubleshooting done to isolate the issue.  I'll be happy to move to a suggested configuration once the problem is identified.

Comment: Well, the only other obvious problem I see is binding to 0.0.0.0. This may exclude localhost, which is by default the IPv6 address ::1. And since it already binds to localhost by default, this just seems unnecessary. I'd remove `-b` entirely and replace it with nothing.

Comment: Ok, I think I've narrowed the problem down to Puma running in cluster mode versus single mode.  When Puma runs in single mode (0 workers), things work, independent of the socket config.  When Puma runs in cluster mode (1 or more workers), it hangs.  Seems to be a Debian 9.8–Puma interaction.

Comment: Are you married to puma? I generally use thin...

Comment: Not married to Puma.  I'll look into thin.  Thank you for your help with all of this.